# Augmented Reality imageRecognition

Tags: android, augmented-reality, image-recognition

[image]

I searched some docs for create imageRecognition. But i didn't get correct path to study for beginner. I need to create above image. I stored my image in database. When image matched i need to display URL in cameraView. How to do? Is any open source available

Comment: @NREZ: See above image

Comment: Ok... It was some format problem and will solve soon hopefully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing that with some picture is complicated. Usually you use black and white images, QR code like.

Maybe you can search here : http://code.google.com/p/andar/

Comment: I need to create like this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPsZyOI0uB4

Comment: Ok then it's not really augmentated reality, you should look for "image recognition" exemple : http://www.kooaba.com/en/home

Comment: @Yume7: Why it's not augmented Reality? Because they are displaying information on camera layer, while image recognition.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear enough ^^ as you say it is augmented reality but "image recognition" are key words that can help you find what you are trying to achieve faster. If you find some solutions that would be nice to edit your post with it ;) good luck

Comment: It's nice. But in that API all images are stored in their website. I need to store all images in my own server and then apply image Recognition. How can i do?

Comment: Here is another solution (not free) https://developer.qualcomm.com/discover/mobile-platforms/android if you need your "own" you will be forced to use OpenCV i guess http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Answer (score 0):

check [opencv features2d module](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography), especially sift, surf and homography methods.

after you find the region of the feature, you can place your AR object onto it using [openGL methods](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html).

you may need to search and read tutorials about both openCV and openGL libraries.

Comment: OpenGL es1 or es2 is certainly one of the best solutions (or maybe the best)  the only problem is that it is not an easy way for the beginners ^^

Comment: well dealing with AR is not beginners' job. if he needs the AR object to be smaller and bigger in case of any camera movement, then he needs camera calibration, too.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the world of computer vision - you will encounter much satisfaction and much frustration. There are a few problems you are facing here. Firstly, it isn't a straight image recognition problem because you view the image not necessarily face-on at 90 degrees. I suggest you first detect the orientation of the surface before you, then apply a 3D transform so that the surface is perpendicular to your gaze direction, then do regular 2D image recognition on that. Even with the last step you still have to be able to detect at different scales and orientations.

I don't know specific good techniques for the first two steps, but you can google.

For the last stem, you can search for Viola-Jones detector (2001), which will work for upright orientation. Also just search "image recognition", see what you get. Alternatively, if you want to try writing your own, you can start by calculating a "fourier power spectrum" which is invariant to size and location. Google more for what that means.

For implemenations of a lot of algorithms, google "openCV".